pySpark: how to create a dynamic map from an array
I have a dataframe with marks in each subject and favourite_subjects. The data look like this:
data = [
  (1, 85, 90, 78, 88, 92, 75, 80, ["Math", "Science"]),
  (2, 70, 95, 82, 79, 85, 88, 91, ["English", "History"]),
  (3, None, 76, 90, 92, 85, 87, 89, ["Math", "Science", "English"])
  ]
columns = ["student_id", "Math", "Science", "English", "History", "Geography", "Physics", "Chemistry", "favorite_subjects"]

Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

Question: I need to add a new column favorite_subject_marks should contain data as a dictionary, with favourite subject name as a key and marks as value.
NOTE:

I am using databricks and I will not be able to use RDD  .
the number of columns in the datset could change over time, So I cant use the hard coded column names in case when statements.

Could some one please help me we can do this dynamic mapping?
Expected output:
Student_id.      favorite_subject_marks 
1   [Math -> 85 , Science -> 90]
2   [English ->82 , History -> 79]
3.  [Math -> None, Science -> 76, English-> 90]

I tried to use transform, expr function to create the dynamic mapping but ended up with Column cant be iterable error.
